# How can I scrape data from a website using the Jaunt library?

Tags: java, jaunt-api

I want to get the title from this website: http://feeds.foxnews.com/foxnews/latest

like this example:

```
<title><![CDATA[SUCCESSFUL INTERCEPT Pentagon confirms it shot down ICBM-type target]]></title>
```

and it will show text like this:

"SUCCESSFUL INTERCEPT Pentagon confirms it shot down ICBM-type target
US conducts successful missile intercept test, Pentagon says"

Here's my code. I have used jaunt library.

I don't know why it shows text only "foxnew.com"

```
import com.jaunt.JauntException;
import com.jaunt.UserAgent;

public class p8_1
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent();
            userAgent.visit("http://feeds.foxnews.com/foxnews/latest"); 
            String title = userAgent.doc.findFirst
("<title><![CDATA[SUCCESSFUL INTERCEPT Pentagon confirms it shot down ICBM-type target]]></title>").getText();
              System.out.println("\n " + title); 


        } catch (JauntException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you try String title = userAgent.doc.findFirst("<title>").getText() and share the output?

Comment: I tried it. out put is the same  show text only "foxnew.com"

 thank you anyway  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for element types, not values.

Try the following to get the title text of each item in the feed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent();
        userAgent.visit("http://feeds.foxnews.com/foxnews/latest");

        Elements items = userAgent.doc.findEach("<item>");
        Elements titles = items.findEach("<title>");

        for (Element title : titles) {
            String titleText = title.getComment(0).getText();
            System.out.println(titleText);
        }
    } catch (JauntException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```